# Changing jinja_env from a blueprint

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to register a new jinja global on my blueprint using the `Blueprint` object. However, it appears that `Blueprint` objects do not have `jinja_env` attributes; how can I register a new jinja global attributes?

Here's the `__init__.py` of the blueprint, this does not work:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

uploader = Blueprint('uploader', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from . import views
from . import models

current_app.jinja_env.globals['form_token'] = views.generate_form_token
```

Nor does this:

```
uploader.jinja_env.globals['form_token'] = views.generate_form_token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Blueprint.app_template_global`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_template_global) decorator to register a global function to the jinja env.

```
uploader.app_template_global(views.generate_form_token)
```

Or in views.py:

```
@uploader.app_template_global
def generate_form_token():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem using Flask with Jinja 2 and having trouble registering global template using **app_template_global** decorator.

I used ***add_app_template_global decorator*** described here [Flask API refernce](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.add_app_template_global)

The following code works for Flask (0.10.1) blueprints with Jinja2(2.8).
Here is the `__init__.py` file.

```
from flask import Blueprint
blueprint_name = Blueprint('blueprint_name', __name__) 

from . import views
```

add the decorator to function in main file [in my case `views.py`] file.
Here is the `views.py` file.

```
from . import blueprint_name

@blueprint_name.add_app_template_global
def function_name():
    pass
```

You can then call this function in Jinja2 template as

```
<h1>
    {{ function_name() }}
<h1>
```